# Why is setState function in flutter not working?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am working with APIs and using a delete method to delete an item with a unique id from a list. The delete method is working but I need to reload the page everytime I want to see the results. I tried to add a setState() function inside a button and call the delete method from there but it is not working. I am not getting any errors however.

Delete method:

```
Future <void> deleteData(todo) async {
var urlToUpdate = Uri.parse('https://todoapp-api.apps.k8s.gu.se/todos/${todo.id}?key=${testKey}');

try {
  await http.delete(urlToUpdate, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: jsonEncode({
    "id": todo.id,
    "title": todo.title,
    "done": todo.done

  }));

} catch (err) {
  print(err);
}
```

}

setState method:

```
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                   setState(() {
                   var deleteTodo = TodoItem(id: id, title: '', done: false);
                   deleteData(deleteTodo);
                });
              },
```

I can't provide the whole code because it is too large but the delete method comes right after :

class _TodoListState extends State {

and before initState and Widget build.

My TodoItemsList works like this:

```
 Future fetchPosts() async {
try {
  await getKey();
  final response = await HTTP.get(Uri.parse('${url}${todos}${testKey}'));
  final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);


  setState(() {
    TodoItemsList = jsonData;
  });
  

  print(jsonData);

} catch (err) {
  print('Error');
}
```

}

This empty list is just above the Widget build

```
 List TodoItemsList = [];
```

This widget is inside by body property:

```
    Widget getBody() {
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: TodoItemsList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return getCard(TodoItemsList[index]);
});
```

}

Comment: Could you add the code for the deleteData method to the question? And if possible the complete code of this screen.

Comment: Yes just did, cant include the whole screen though it is too much code and wasn't formatted the right way anyway in the question

Comment: Look at what you provided I can say that there is no way for setState to update your widget because I don't see any changes being made, this deleteTodo is not linked to any widget. Your request also does not generate any changes to your tree.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of what i can do? some people said that I need to manually remove the item from the list inside the setState function but i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wait until the deleteData finished.

After that, remove the local TodoItem from the list by yourself.

```dart
child: IconButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    var deleteTodo = TodoItem(id: id, title: '', done: false);
    await deleteData(deleteTodo);
    setState(() {
      => remove TodoItem from the local list =<
    });
  }
```

Because network request usually takes times. You should display something like `CircularProgressIndicator` when `deleteData` is running. But that's another story.

Comment: How can I remove it? I receive the single item from a post method in a separate screen, so I don't have it specified in the code, i can only see it in the UI or print it to the console.

Comment: Then how you get the TodoList and display it ?  It's either you remove the item from `List<TodoItem>`, or you trigger a "refresh" to re-request the TodoList from server. Maybe you can show us some more code. So we can figure it out.

Comment: I added some additional code to my question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I did what you said and it worked. It was such an easy solution I don't know how I didn't think of it before. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please mark this answer so it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

**setState** method is used to reflect any change of data over some widget, if you need to remove a element from a list need has that element linked to a widget

example:
If you has

```
listOfMovie = ['Avatar, Avengers', 'Dune', 'Hulk'];
```

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listOfMovie.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Text(listOfMovie[index],
));
```

then

```
child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                   setState(() {
                   listOfMovie = ['Avatar, Avengers'];                   
                });
              },
```

If you notice listOfMovie  is linked to ListView widget